# Quil: Don't even open the window

Tags: clojure, quil

I'm trying to use quil to procedurally generate images. I think it's really great, but I'm not trying to display the image at all. I'm just trying to save the image to a file.

Is it possible to not actually open the window and just save the file directly?

Comment: i came across [this](http://www.tylerlhobbs.com/writings/using-quil-for-artwork) a month or so ago, it's part a series of articles by artist Tyler Hobbs. At the bottom is a section entitled 'Dealing with a Headless Server'. It looks *nix-specific but might be a useful starting point.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I want. ;) Thanks!